# How to change colors of a BarChart in aFreeChart?

Tags: android, graph

I need to change the colors of the differents Bars in my BarChart but I didn't find the way to do this. I've tried with a Plot Object but there is no methods to change the color.

Thanks in advance !

Answer (score 3):

```
    BarRenderer renderer = (BarRenderer) plot.getRenderer();

    renderer.setSeriesPaintType(0, new SolidColor(Color.BLUE));
    renderer.setSeriesPaintType(1, new SolidColor(Color.GREEN));
    renderer.setSeriesPaintType(2, new SolidColor(Color.RED));
```